# DATASTAGE : Job status information for all jobs on DataStage 7.5

Tags: status, etl, datastage

I am using DataStage 7.5 on HP UX system. There are hundreds of jobs stored in different projects, I must go to each and every folder to check the job status.

Isn't there any table or file where the list of the statuses for all jobs is stored?

Thanks in advance,
Lebu

Answer (score 0):

I think the user with datastage admin access can get this information.

Answer (score 0):

In the director, you go to 'View' menu and uncheck 'Show Folders' which will display all the jobs in a single list.